# Google Sheets Query with Variables in the data section

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to create a health related spreadsheet that has a lot of data - a lot of which isn't relevant to this question so I've simplified it. There is a column for each type of pain where you write on a scale of 0-10 how intense your pain was, and another column for any relevant notes. The data is broken up into named ranges to make it easier to display on different tabs (HeadData = Head Pain, ChestData = Chest Pain, etc. - 15 named ranges in total.)

One of the tabs I'm working on has a table where you are viewing only the specific named range, in this case HeadData.
`=query({HeadData}, " Select * where Col1 is not null ",1)`

This works perfectly, but I want to replace {HeadData} with a reference cell to a drop menu so you can select the specific pain area column you want to be displayed.

If I put the reference cell in G1 with a drop down list of the named ranges and select ChestData and try to do

`=query({&G1&}, " Select * where Col1 is not null ",1)`

It is only picking up G1 (ChestData) as a string and not the actual named range.

**So my question is, is there a way to make a drop menu containing named ranges that turn into actual sets of data and not strings when placed in the data section of the query?**

Here is my spreadsheet, any help is appreciated. Thanks!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CcuSV2bbfxsUPPkmj-fru2yYYmmtpXk9LKEF85sxVUw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) for this.

> INDIRECT
> Returns a cell reference specified by a string.

Change your formula to

```
=query({INDIRECT(G1)}, " Select * where Col1 is not null ",1)
```

The INDIRECT function will convert the string in G1 to a cell reference and then the rest of your formula will query the relevant named range.

Comment: You're welcome.  Consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if you think it will be useful to others who see this question.